# ASP.NET - if row count = 1 don't show results

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a repeater with a chid repeater now my aim is to hide the chid repeater if the row count = 1 from its sqlDataSource, if  greater i would like to show all results. i have tried

```
Visible='<%# ((Repeater)Container.NamingContainer).Items.Count >= 1 %>'
```

on the child reapter but it only works for the first iteam in my main repeater row. any suggestions

part of my code--

```
 <div id="image_pic" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" >

            <table style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto 0 auto">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                <img id="mainpic" data-id='<%#"iimage"+Eval("id") %>'  class="img-rounded" alt="" src='<%#Eval("ppic1") %>' style="width: 100%;max-width:550px; max-height:400px " />

                    </td>

                </tr>
              <tr><td>
                  <div style="padding: 3px; margin: 5px; ">
                             <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="thumbs" Visible='<%# ((Repeater)Container.NamingContainer).Items.Count >= 1 %>'><ItemTemplate> 
                      <div id="p1" style="display: inline-block">  


                      <img id="thumbs" alt="" class="img-rounded" src='<%#Eval("thumbs") %>' data-mainpicture='<%#Eval("Picture") %>' style="width: 80px; height: 80px; " /></div>
                         </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>    




                             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="thumbs" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductPictures] WHERE ([Productid] = @Productid)" >
                                 <SelectParameters>
                                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pmap" Name="Productid" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
                                 </SelectParameters>
                             </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My query:

```
SELECT Picture, Productid, thumbs
from
(
    SELECT Picture, Productid, thumbs
    FROM ProductPictures
    GROUP BY Picture, Productid, thumbs
    HAVING COUNT(Productid) <= 2
) as count
where Productid = 40
```

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL at all.

Comment: Sorry but i am looking for a sql query that show all results if the row count is > 1 see my datasource query

Comment: @jarlh did i explain well enough to you. sorry i am a newbie at all this be patient with me

Comment: Are you saying you want a query that returns all products that have more that 1 picture?

Comment: @jarlh simply yes

Comment: SELECT Picture,Productid,thumbs from  (SELECT Picture,Productid,thumbs
  FROM ProductPictures
 GROUP BY Picture,Productid,thumbs
HAVING COUNT(Productid) <=   2)as count
where Productid = 40 ( I am trying something like this) but not getting far

Comment: SELECT 
 Productid ,thumbs,Picture,
 COUNT(*) count
FROM 
 ProductPictures
GROUP BY
 Productid,
 Picture ,
 thumbs
Having
COUNT(*) > 1
-tried also this but i cant just get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns Productid's that have more than one picture. `JOIN` with that result:

```
SELECT Picture, Productid, thumbs
from ProductPictures p
join (SELECT Productid
      FROM ProductPictures
      GROUP BY Productid
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) cnt on p.Productid = cnt.Productid
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "i.Productid" could not be bound.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'Productid'.
 -- results I am getting

Comment: I dont know the forum rules but that answer led me to this, SELECT        p.Picture, p.Productid, p.thumbs, cnt.Productid AS Expr1
FROM            ProductPictures AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Productid
                               FROM            ProductPictures
                               GROUP BY Productid
                               HAVING         (COUNT(*) > 1)) AS cnt ON p.Productid = cnt.Productid
WHERE        (p.Productid = @id).  so yes that above answer was correct

Comment: Are you sure about the LEFT OUTER JOIN? It will return rows without that "more than one picture" match.

Comment: you are right i spoke in a rush... I changed it to this <br> SELECT ProductPictures.Productid, ProductPictures_1.thumbs, ProductPictures_1.Picture FROM  ProductPictures INNER JOIN ProductPictures AS ProductPictures_1 ON ProductPictures.Productid = ProductPictures_1.Productid GROUP BY ProductPictures.Productid, ProductPictures_1.thumbs, ProductPictures_1.Picture HAVING        (COUNT(*) >= 2) AND (ProductPictures.Productid = @id)